Как подписаться на изменения состояния переменной react?
Почему при изменении переменной состояния currentPage он изменяется лишь в dom но не в коде и как с этим работать?
const ReactComponent = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    
  const fetchData = async () => {
     const response = await FetchDataService.get(currentPage); // не изменилось
  }
    
  const goNextPage = () => {
   setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
   fetchData();
  }
        
  const goPrevPage = () => {
   setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
   fetchData();
  }

  return(
   <section>
     <span>Строк: {pageSize}</span>
     <button onClick={goPrevPage}>{`< пред`}</button>
     <span>{currentPage} из {totalPages}</span>
     <button onClick={goNextPage}>{`след >`}</button>
   </section>
   )
}


Может вам нужно функцию завернуть в useCallback/useMemo (не уверен, что из этого тут подойдет). Или проще уже передать параметром нужную страницу.

Данные сначала меняются в переменных, а уже потом реакт их отрисовывает. С чего вы решили, что в переменные не меняются, при этом меняя значения в браузере? Дополните вопрос большими подробностями и детальнее опишите, где что вызывается, как работает сейчас и какого поведения вы хотите достичь

я всё объяснил. В коде комментарий где должно меняться, но не меняется

Если вы про эту строку const response = await FetchDataService.get(currentPage) то что тут и почему должно меняться? переменная response вообще бессмысленна. Что такое FetchDataService и что за метод такой get, куда вы передаете currentPage? Вот что из этого "не изменилось" и какое поведение вы ожидаете(что должно меняться)?

до первого комментатора вроде дошло. На html продемонстрировано две кнопки. Как думаете что эти две кнопки делают? Вопрос уточнил.

currentPage поменяется при следующей отрисовке страницы. Вам нужно запрашивать данные при отрисовке, а не тогда, когда вы вызываете setCurrentPage. Ну вернее не страницы, а соответствующих контролов изменившихся отрисовка имеется в виду. Почитайте примеры использования useState, там во всех примерах есть правильные шаблоны использования.

@CrazyElf можно по подробнее. Как получить данные при отрисовке?

Что делают 2 кнопки, продемонстрированные в html? Отрисованы браузером и показываются. А то что вы уточнили про currentPage - ну так вот currentPage у вас примитив (число), а не объект, как таковой. Лучше бы было вопрос составить вида Когда я жму кнопку, вызывается функция ** в котороя я делаю и далее это ** и ожидаю что будет так то, но вместо этого я вижу/происходит?

Изменение состояния компонента - это асинхронная операция и надеяться что setter отработает быстрее, чем следующая функция - не правильно.
Я вижу 2 варианта.
Первый, сохранять "новое" значение в отдельную переменную и передавать в фукнцию для вызова:
const fetchData = async (newPage) => {
  const response = await FetchDataService.get(newPage); 
}

const goNextPage = () => {
  const newPage = ++currentPage;
  setCurrentPage(newPage);
  fetchData(newPage);
}

const goPrevPage = () => {
  const newPage = --currentPage;
  setCurrentPage(newPage);
  fetchData(newPage);
}

Либо в явном виде опираться на состояние переменных компонентов, подписавшись на их изменение с помощью useEffect
const goNextPage = () => {
  setCurrentPage(++currentPage);
}

const goPrevPage = () => {
  setCurrentPage(--currentPage);
}

useEffect(() => {
  FetchDataService.get(currentPage);
}, [currentPage]);


Да не в асинхронности дело. Это by design так, что значение устанавливаемой useState переменной изменится только при следующем рендере.

@CrazyElf setState говорит, измени значение. Значение меняется(асинхронно - в будущем) и далее идет вызов функции с перерисовкой элементов в рендере, потом вызов useEffect всех зависимых переменных, которые были изменены относительно предыдущего рендера.

await внутри функции без async

@Grundy Точно. Поправил. Туда бы еще .then пихнуть, но не понятно, что с этим делать далее и нужен ли сам ответ в этом компоненте

а если мне в useEffect нужно запихать доп логику помимо фетч даты? и вообще я не хочу делать фетч дату каждое обновление старницы

@yava43 Вам никто не запрещает расширять useEffect новой логикой. Так же можно создавать много useEffect со своим набором зависимостей. Если надо, что бы useEffect сработал только один раз(установка компоента), то используется пусой массив зависимостей([])

если fetchData должен вызываться при изменении currentPage - нужно добавить useEffect с соответствующей зависимостью
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

useEffect(()=>{
    (async ()=>{
        const response = await FetchDataService.get(currentPage); // не изменилось
    })();
}, [currentPage]);

const goNextPage = () => {
   setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
}

const goPrevPage = () => {
   setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
}


currentPage поменяется при следующей отрисовке контрола, инициированной изменением currentPage через вызов setCurrentPage. Поэтому вам нужно запрашивать данные сразу при отрисовке контрола, а не тогда, когда вы вызываете setCurrentPage, чтобы поменять состояние переменной. То есть примерно так (надеюсь, этот код находится внутри контрола React, а не сам по себе):
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

// сама эта функция странная - её значение никуда не идёт, её нужно переписать
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await FetchDataService.get(currentPage); // не изменилось
}

fetchData(); // получаем текущее значение currentPage и используем его

const goNextPage = () => {
   setCurrentPage(x => x + 1); // лучше менять переменные так
}

const goPrevPage = () => {
   setCurrentPage(x => x - 1); // лучше менять переменные так
}

[...]

P.S. Засомневался, может я неправильно понимаю React, но нет, вот цитата из документации:

The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

Ну и там дальше про то, что если значение выставлено тоже самое, то компонент не обновится и т.д.

Там проблема в том, что вызов сеттера(setCurrentPage) это асинхронная операция и когда она произойдет - неизвестно. Поэтому вызов fetchData происходит с предыдущим состоянием, а само изменение currentPage произойдет позже. А в вашем примере еще есть "косяк", что кажое изменение в состоянии компонента(допусти там еще 10 переменных) будет приводить к запуску функции( а если фукнция сама меняет состояние - то к ошибке too many re-renders )

@SwaD Ну, в документации чётко сказано, что состояние обновляется для следующего рендера, а не для текущего. Вот то, что может не только это состояние поменяться - теперь мне понятно, в чём проблема и для чего нужен useEffect, спасибо.
